# Script via Link requer double click a primeira vez que é requested

Tags: javascript, front-end

Tenho 3 inline-block Divs numa row. Estas divs contêm 1 paragrafo de texto com um link no final para extender a div e imprimir os restantes paragrafos.
No final da div extendida, existe outro link que devolve a div ao seu estado normal.
Para conseguir isto, uso as seguintes scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function mor() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.more').click(function () {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).load('content-box_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('id') + '-p');
            return false;
        });

    });
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function res() {
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.reset').click(function(){
              $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).load('reset_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('id')+'-p');
            return false;
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

O link das divs têm este aspecto:

```
<p>Mobile sales System – Mobile application for Pre- Sales and Auto sales, distribution and tecnical services. Available to PDA and Tablet.  <a class="more" id="sales" href="javascript:mor()" style="text-decoration: none;">[+]</a></p>
```

O conteudo dentro do ficheiro "content-box_en.phtml":

```
<p id="sales-p"><?= mb_convert_encoding('Mobile sales System – Mobile application for Pre- Sales and Auto sales, distribution and tecnical services. Available to PDA and Tablet.', 'UTF-8') ?></p>
<p id="sales-p"><?= mb_convert_encoding('Mobile sales System – Mobile application for Pre- Sales and Auto sales.', 'UTF-8')?><a class="reset" id="sales" href="javascript:res()" style="text-decoration: none;">[-]</a></p>
```

Esta funcional, o problema surge quando clico no link pela a primeira vez. Tenho que dar double click a primeira vez que chamo a função, mas depois ja funciona com um single click...

Não percebo a razão para este comportamento.
Não estou muito dentro de Javascript, e qualquer ajuda era apreciada.

Answer (score 1):

possivelmente é pq esta fazendo errado na chamada da fc, $(document).ready é equivalente ao window.onload, o certo é ficar assim

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function res() {
      $('.reset').click(function(){
          $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).load('reset_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('id')+'-p');
        return false;
    });
}
 });
```

e a sua ancora href="#" pois no carregamento do script ja vai associar o .reset ao script de click

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode, e na minha opinião: deve, adicionar todos os scripts dentro de uma única função de leitura do documento pronto. 
Não vejo necessidade de ouvir vários eventos iguais ou de procurar o código em vários lugares quando deveriam estar todos num só.

Seu JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.more').click(function () {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).load('content-box_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('id') + '-p');
        });

        $('.reset').click(function(){
              $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).load('reset_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('id')+'-p');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Seu HTML:

```
<p>Mobile sales System – Mobile application for Pre- Sales and Auto sales, distribution and tecnical services. Available to PDA and Tablet.  
    <a class="more" id="sales" style="text-decoration: none;">[+]</a>
</p>
```

Como tu define o ouvinte de acordo com a classe do objeto, não se faz necessário chamar uma função para disparar (como tu faz aqui `href="javascript:mor()"`, e é por isso que é necessário clicar duas vezes para disprar a função efetivamente. 
Note que, quando tu define uma função, ele não atribuiu o evento, já que a função não foi chamada. Depois de chamar a função no onclick, aí sim, existe o ouvinte para a classe, agora sim, vai disparar qndo clicar, entende?

Então defina tudo para sua classe ou id, ou defina tudo no onclick, mas usando os dois e nessa ordem, não tem outra forma de acontecer, senão ter que clicar duas vezes: uma que define o ouvinte e a outra que dispara o evento.

Comment: Resolveu o problema do double click mas agora não consegue voltar ao seu estado original ..
Foi por esta mesma razão que modifquei o script como mostrei em cima.
Parece que ele nao reconhece o link que surgiu depois de extender a div..

Comment: Adiciona o conteúdo dentro de uma div com uma classe ou id, aí pra voltar ao estado original é só remover essa div.

Comment: Mas a div original não é substituida no decorrer da função?
A script fica sem reconhecer o link ".more" da div original (já substituida de volta)... O conceito era utilizador poder alargar e diminuir as divs individualmente sem dar refresh a página.

Comment: Adiciona seu HTML, por gentileza. Toda a div que expande e etc.